# Finding Expected Value of $f(x)= 0.10e^{-x/10}$

Tags: probability, integration

I have the following probability density function:

$$f(x)= \cases{0.10e^{-x/10} \hspace{0.5cm}   x \geq 0\\
         0     \hspace{1.9cm}\text{otherwise}}$$

and need help answering the following question:
What is $P(X\leq E(X))$? What does this tell you about the distribution of X?

When I tried to complete the above question, I obtained a value of 10 for the expected value and 0.6321 as the probability that the random variable is less than the expected value. But I don't know what this tells me about the distribution, nor if I integrated correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. I tried helping with the formatting, please let me know if something went wrong

Comment: This tells you that the median is to the left of the mean, thus, the Pearson median skewness, or second skewness coefficient, is positive. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Pearson.27s_second_skewness_coefficient_.28median_skewness.29

Comment: it's the exponential distribution, it has a long tail on the right, if you look at a graph of the distribution it can take large values on the right, but with low probability - I agree with your calculation, it is 1 - 1/e and the answer 10 is 1 / $\lambda$ a standard result - so that is good

Comment: can you imagine a distribution function for which the expected value and the median are the same? I think this will help you understand the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do this.

1) Here is the pdf:

$$f(x)=\frac{e^{-\frac{x}{10}}}{10}$$

2) Find the mean:

$$E[X] = \int_0^{\infty} x f(x) = x \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{10}}}{10} = 10 $$

3) Now, let's find $$P(X \leq E[X]) = P(X \leq 10)$$

$$ = 1-e^{-\frac{x}{10}} = 1-e^{-\frac{10}{10}} =  1-e^{-1}= 1-\frac{1}{e} = 0.632121$$

4) So what does this tell you about the distribution? It tells you that most events or the mass of the distribution is below or less than the mean.